# @ManyToMany relation with composite key and extra column, nested column in intermediate table

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, composite-key

this is my current situation :
I have a [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdehE.png) like this. In the intermediate tables I have 1 more extra column. The problem here is in the table "Period_Area_CC", the column "Area_CompNo" is referenced by 2 columns ("CompNo" from table "CC" and "Area_CompNo" from tablle "Period_Area")

And here is my mapping

```
public class Area extends BaseEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AreaId id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "area", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AreaPeriod> areaPeriods;
}

public class AreaPeriod implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "periodAssignmentID")
    private Long periodID;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "areaID")
    private Long areaID;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "companyNo")
    private Long companyNo;

    private Long parentId;

    @Column(name = "hierarchyPath")
    private String hierarchyPath;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "areaID", referencedColumnName = "areaID", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "companyNo", referencedColumnName = "companyNo", updatable = false, insertable = false)})
    private Area area;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "periodAssignmentID", referencedColumnName = "periodAssignmentID", updatable = false, insertable = false)})
    private VirtualAreaPeriodDefinition period;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AreaPeriod> children;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "periodAssignmentID", referencedColumnName = "periodAssignmentID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", referencedColumnName = "areaID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "companyNo", referencedColumnName = "companyNo", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    private AreaPeriod parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "areaPeriod", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CostCenterAreaPeriod> costCenterAreaPeriods;
}
public class CostCenterAreaPeriod implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "companyNo")
    private Long companyNo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "periodAssignmentID")
    private Long periodId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "areaID")
    private Long areaId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CostCenterEnum")
    private Long costCenterEnum;

    private String hierarchyPath;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "areaID", referencedColumnName = "areaID", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "companyNo", referencedColumnName = "companyNo", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "periodAssignmentID", referencedColumnName = "periodAssignmentID", updatable = false, insertable = false)})
    private AreaPeriod areaPeriod;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "CompanyNo", referencedColumnName = "companyNo", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "CostCenterEnum", referencedColumnName = "CostCenterEnum", updatable = false, insertable = false)})
    private CostCenter costCenter;
}
public class CostCenter extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2290076530189347245L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private CXCostCenterPK id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "costCenter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CostCenterAreaPeriod> costCenterAreaPeriods;
}
```

Because I have marked the relation with insertable and updateable false so I have to insert manually.
So is there any better solution, so I just need to map the relation on the entity, then JPA will handle the insert/update/delete funtion?

Updated :

```
public class CXCostCenterPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 658550094878047277L;

    @Column(name = "CompanyNo")
    private Long companyNo;

    @Column(name = "CostCenterEnum")
    private Long costCenterEnum;
}
public class AreaId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "companyNo", length = 5, nullable = false)
    private Long companyNo;

    @Column(name = "areaID", length = 11, nullable = false)
    private Long areaEnum;
}
```

Comment: Where is the class `AreaId`?

Comment: I think its not necessary but I'll add at the bottom